# WPF Animation: Detect if any animation is in process?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

Is there a quick way to determine if *any* animation in a WPF control is processing.

I have a treeview where I am animating the expansion of the tree nodes, and I would like to wait until all those animations are complete before scrolling the focused item into view.  I'd prefer not to track the progress of all my storyboards independently.

Ideally my pseudo code would look something like this:

```
myTreeView.ExpandAll(); // I have written this part

while (myTreeView.IsAnimating()) // I need the 'IsAnimating' property or extension method
{
   // wait
}

selectedTreeviewItem.BringIntoView(); // I have written this too.
```

Comment: Have you tried the StoryBoard "Completed" event?

Comment: Since there are multiple storyboards animating (one for every treeview item that is expanding), I'm not sure I'll know when the last one completes.

Comment: So just increment a counter in your storyboard begin events and decrement the counter on the completed events, and if the counter is zero after decrementing, then all animations are complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the storyboard's [completed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979733%28VS.95%29.aspx#Y960)?  You will have to either use an event or a different thread, or you will block the UI thread with your while statement and no animations will play.

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid, since I am triggering anywhere between 1 and x animations simultaneously... that is one fallback option I am considering, however.

Comment: Well your answer is essentially it.  What I was missing was using EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(...,Storyboard.CompletedEvent,...) in the static constructor of myTreeView so that I can watch all the animation complete.